# Issue with micro python in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, micropython

I installed MicroPython in Pycharm and enabled MicroPython support, however when I open the project there is a message near the top of the project saying "Packages required for Raspberry Pi pico support not found" then it has an option to download the required packages. When I click on it, it says they are downloading then right before it would normally finish it says 'package installation failed'. I have tried restarting Pycharm and uninstalling and reinstalling micro python and nothing so far has worked.
Any suggestions on how to get the missing packages to download?